# Example of continuous map

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm looking for an **example** (not argument) of map $f$ such that $$f : (\mathbb{R},T) \to (\mathbb{R},T_2)$$ is continuous but $$f : (\mathbb{R},T_{cf}) \to (\mathbb{R},T_2)$$ not, being $T:=\{V \subset \mathbb{R} : 0 \notin V\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$, $T_{cf}$ the co-finite topology and $T_2$ the one given by the Euclidean metric.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $f : (\mathbb{R},T) \to (\mathbb{R},T_2)$ is continuous. Put $a:=f(0)$. Then the set $$f^{-1}(\Bbb R\setminus \{a\})=\{x\in\Bbb R:f(x)\neq a\}\not\ni 0$$ is open. Therefore $f^{-1}(\Bbb R\setminus \{a\})=\emptyset$, which implies that $f\equiv a$, i.e. $f$ is constant. This function is also continuous in euclidean topology. This shows that, unfortunately, there aren't any such example.

Comment: What do you mean? If $f$ is continous in one case also is in the another case? Thanks!

Comment: @LH8 yes. I showed that the only functions from $\Bbb R$ with topology $T$ to $\Bbb R$ with topology $T_2$ are constants, which are always continuous. This is not automatic, since both topologies are not comparable (neither of them is coarser, neither is finer).